# Call commandlink action from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, jakarta-ee

im trying to call a bean from a javascript, using a h:commandLink.

i have a commandLink

```
                <h:commandLink action="#{bean.go()}"
                    styleClass="simple-submit-button" id="uLink">
                    <f:param name="userId" value="#{param['userId']}" />
                </h:commandLink>
```

which calls my bean.

and want to call this commandLink from javascript, like this:

```
document.getElementById('uLink').click();
```

but i m always getting the error: document.getElementById('uLink') is null.

I tried this:

- setting h:commandLink immediate="false" and instead of document.getElementById('uLink').click() i used document.getElementById('uLink').immediate=true;
- usinng h:commandButton instead.
- using document.getElementById('formId:uLink').click();

Has anyone an idea how i get this work?

Comment: Show the resulting HTML. It's likely that the HTML id is not simply `uLink`.

Comment: do view source and see the id of the button , it might look like someContainerID:uLink or someFormID:uLink and not just uLink so you might need to use document.getElementById('someFormID:uLink').click();

Comment: you're righ the id is 'formId:uLink'(checked with firebug), so now i dont get the error anymore. but it still doesnt work.

Comment: That's a different problem :)

Comment: its not really a different problem. the question is still unsolved: why does the link not calling the action? Or is the script not calling the link? dont know how to find it out. already checked this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do `view source` in you browser and look on the exact the id of the button , it might look like `someContainerID:uLink` or `someFormID:uLink` and not just `uLink` so you might need to use

```
document.getElementById('someFormID:uLink').click();
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('someContainerID:uLink').click();
```

Comment: @Hitesh, than improve your selector, make unique class for your button/use jquery "ends with selector" etc... You always should have a known selector for your button.